# How to run secure service fabric stateful service in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, replication, azure-service-fabric

I've been able to get this to work locally using the following Settings.xml file.

```
<Section Name="ReplicatorSecurityConfig">
  <Parameter Name="CredentialType" Value="X509" />
  <Parameter Name="FindType" Value="FindByThumbprint" />
  <Parameter Name="FindValue" Value="InsertLocalhostThumbprintHere" />
  <Parameter Name="StoreLocation" Value="LocalMachine" />
  <Parameter Name="StoreName" Value="My" />
  <Parameter Name="ProtectionLevel" Value="EncryptAndSign" />
  <Parameter Name="AllowedCommonNames" Value="localhost" />
</Section>
```

This however does not work in the real cluster in Azure that was setup securely using a cert.  Here is my modified Settings.xml that I thought would work but it is not.

```
<Section Name="ReplicatorSecurityConfig">
  <Parameter Name="CredentialType" Value="X509" />
  <Parameter Name="FindType" Value="FindByThumbprint" />
  <Parameter Name="FindValue" Value="InsertClusterThumbprintHere" />
  <Parameter Name="StoreLocation" Value="LocalMachine" />
  <Parameter Name="StoreName" Value="My" />
  <Parameter Name="ProtectionLevel" Value="EncryptAndSign" />
  <Parameter Name="AllowedCommonNames" Value="testapp1.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com" />
</Section>
```

What happens on the real cluster in azure is the Secondary get stuck in status "In Build" and their role says IdleSecondary instead of the normal ActiveSecondary that I'm used to.

What settings should I use for AllowedCommonNames?  What exactly is this doing?  Why does it not use RemoteCommonNames?  I thought AllowedCommonNames was [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/system.fabric.x509credentials.allowedcommonnames.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in favor of RemoteCommonNames.  I've tried, even locally if I modify AllowedCommonNames to RemoteCommonNames it breaks my service locally.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I solved my own issue, my modified config was fine for the cloud the only difference was I needed to log into each VM underneath the VM scale set in the cluster and add the public key of the cert to the trusted root since this was a self signed cert.  After doing that, things started working.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a realistic solution. What are you going to do when you have 100 machines in your cluster? Log into every single one of them one by one?

Comment: I added code on startup of my service to check for cert and install it if it was not there.

Comment: You could just use an ARM template deployment to install the certifciates from keyvault automatically...